# Pattern matching on a Try lazy val in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to pattern match on a `lazy val`, declared as a `Try`, like this?

```
lazy val kafkaProducer: Try[producer.KafkaProducer[Array[Byte], String]] = Try(kafkaProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer())
...
kafkaProducer.get match {
  case Success(_) => Source.single(producerRecord()).runWith(Producer.plainSink(kafkaProducerSettings, kafkaProducer.get))
  case Failure(x) => Future.failed(x)
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : akka.actor.Status.Success
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Array[Byte],String]
[error]         case Success(_) => Source.single(producerRecord()).runWith(Producer.plainSink(kafkaProducerSettings, kafkaProducer.get))
```

Note, this alternative code works, but I'm not sure it's the "Scala way":

```
lazy val kafkaProducer: producer.KafkaProducer[Array[Byte], String] = kafkaProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer()
...
val tryAccessLazyKafkaProducer = Try(kafkaProducer)
if (tryAccessLazyKafkaProducer.isSuccess) {
  Source.single(producerRecord()).runWith(Producer.plainSink(kafkaProducerSettings, kafkaProducer))
} else {
  Future.failed(tryAccessLazyKafkaProducer.failed.get)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely possible, you just have the wrong `Success` type imported:

```
found   : akka.actor.Status.Success
```

You need `scala.util.Success` instead

One thing you mustn't do is call `Try.get`, which will explode if the returned type is a `Failure`. Instead, do:

```
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure

kafkaProducer match {
    case Success(producer) => Source.single(producerRecord()).runWith(Producer.plainSink(kafkaProducerSettings, producer))
    case failure: Failure => failure
}
```

`lazy` is just a language construct which makes sure the value is only ever evaluated once. The underlying type, whether lazy or not, is still a `Try` which you can do what you do with it.